# Google App Engine SDK ERROR- "No Module named requests"

Tags: google-app-engine, python-requests, google-app-engine-python

I installed the App engine SDK, then did a pip install requests and pip install requests-toolbelt (under VENV). when running the app in the local development server - I get the following error:

```
ERROR    2017-05-31 18:14:52,315 cgi.py:122] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/assafshamia/Freebird/Techradar/dev/scraper.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I followed the steps of installing a 3rd party library (appengine_config.py and install requests under /lib)

what is going on???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following code to my Python app (`main.py`) in order to access the libraries at `/lib`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#adding_third_party_python_libraries), you need to add the requests library code to your application directory. `pip install` is not enough.

> You can include third party Python libraries with your application by
>   putting the code in your application directory.

Edit:

Additionally:

> The include path of the Python module includes your application's root directory, which is the directory containing the app.yaml file. Python modules that you create in your application's root directory are available using a path from the root. Don't forget to create the required **init**.py files in your sub-directories so that Python recognizes those sub-directories as packages.

Comment: but I did pip install -t lib/ <library_name> and the library code now resides under /lib in my app dir.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the second portion from the documentation. Did you do this as well?

Comment: I added an empty __init__.py file at the lib/ sub dir of my app.yaml dir. didn't help. The docs provide a clear way of referring to this /lib dir by adding the vendor.add('lib') to appengine_config.py.